# is it mandatory to specify 'wlServerPort' value in wlclient.properties file?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

If I am not passing any value for port number even then when the build is finished, worklight is putting `wlServerPort = 80` as default value. I am using Worklight 6.2. Is it mandatory to specify 'wlServerPort' value in wlclient.properties file?

```
       <app-builder
        worklightserverhost="http://1.2.3.4/myAppContext"
        applicationFolder="${project.home}/apps/myApp"
        nativeProjectPrefix="MyApp"
        outputFolder="${basedir}/bin"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will not specify a port value, Worklight will assume a default port value.
To avoid any possible issues, specify the correct port value for your server in the file.